# MongoDB aggregation: sum of a field inside an array data and project that on parent collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have two collection one is invoice and another one is payment

invoice collection looks like this

```
{
  _id: "123",
  client: "ABC"
}
```

payment collection looks like

```
{
  _id: "456",
  invoiceId: "123",
  amount: 100
},
{
  _id: "789",
  invoiceId: "123",
  amount: 50
}
```

i want output like

```
{
  _id: "123",
  client: "ABC",
  amount: 150
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it with `$lookup`, `$project` and `$sum` like this:

```js
db.invoice.aggregate([
    {
        //you can remove this stage if you don't need to filter your data
        "$match": {
            "_id": "123"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "payment",
            "as": "payments",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "invoiceId"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "client": 1,
            "amount": {
                "$sum": "$payments.amount"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following aggregation so that you don't need to project the items manually:

```
db.invoices.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "payments",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "invoiceId",
      as: "payments"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      amount: {
        $sum: "$payments.amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      payments: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wTOWew_uSI4)